# Maven automatically increasing size of edited Stanford NLP file

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, stanford-nlp

I am using stanford's core nlp models jar file: `stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar`.

I edited and cut a lot of the contents of this file so that form 340 MB, its only about 7 MB. When I build this jar file with maven, it adds it in the .m2/repository/ and makes a new folder edu/ and dumps everything in it. When I look at the size of the jar files, it shows me 7 MB.

However, when I upload!this file to my server, it for some reason shows that his file is 329 MB? I tried solving this problem many ways but could not do it. How is maven making this file from 7 MB to 329 MB even when it tells me that it is 7 MB?

This is the pom.xml for all of the jar files in stanford-corenlp-3.5.2

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.2</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Stanford CoreNLP</name>
  <description>Stanford CoreNLP provides a set of natural language analysis tools which can take raw English language text input and give the base forms of words, their parts of speech, whether they are names of companies, people, etc., normalize dates, times, and numeric quantities, mark up the structure of sentences in terms of phrases and word dependencies, and indicate which noun phrases refer to the same entities. It provides the foundational building blocks for higher level text understanding applications.</description>
  <url>http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>GNU General Public License Version 3</name>
      <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt</url>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <scm>
    <url>http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-2015-04-21.zip</url>
    <connection>http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-2015-04-21.zip</connection>
  </scm>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>christopher.manning</id>
      <name>Christopher Manning</name>
      <email>manning@stanford.edu</email>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>john.bauer</id>
      <name>John Bauer</name>
      <email>horatio@gmail.com</email>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.io7m.xom</groupId>
      <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.jollyday</groupId>
      <artifactId>jollyday</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library</groupId>
      <artifactId>ejml</artifactId>
      <version>0.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-models</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>${project.basedir}/stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar</file>
                  <type>jar</type>
                  <classifier>models</classifier>
                </artifact>
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

By the way, my jar file is also called `stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar`.
Also, I am using a wildly server

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you try naming it something like stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-small-models.jar and see if you keep getting the same problem.  The first thing I would want to rule out is somehow the original .jar being fetched.

Comment: Ok. But what about the Pom.xml file that maven uses to build the index? Should I make this change on the Pom.xml too?

Comment: Yes I would create a completely separate artifact with a different name.

Comment: I actually tried creating a separate artifact (but without changing the Pom.xml) and it still somehow got the original. But let me give this a shot again